# Python subprocess log stdout and stderr to named pipe

Tags: python-3.x, named-pipes

I am starting a child process with subprocess.Popen in python3 and I need to direct all the output from stdout and stderr of this child process to a named pipe which is already created by some other process. There are other processes also writing to the same named pipe. Is there a way to do this?

i tried passing it as a string but that is not what is expected as popen needs file handles

```
subprocess.Popen(my_cmd, stdout="/path/to/named_pipe", stderr="/path/to/named_pipe", env=my_env)
```

Comment: Can you show your code so far?

Comment: @7koFnMiP there isnt much code, but i did add what i have right now